# How to use @Lazy annotation in a class constructor with Lombok?

Tags: spring, lazy-loading, lombok

Given a class AnimalService:

```
public class AnimalService{

      private DogService dogService;

      private AnimalService(@Lazy DogService dogService){
          this.dogService = dogService;
      }
    }
}
```

In this case if I want to use Lombok annotations is there a way to keep the @Lazy loading?

The following code will do the same as the above code?

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AnimalService{
  @Lazy
  private DogService dogService;
}

@Lazy
public class DogService{
//code
}
```

Is this an appropriate way to use @Lazy annotation with Lombok?

Comment: Why don't you just test it? If it works, then it's legit (probably some spring magic to match the constructor parameters with the fields to get the appropriate annotations). However, I assume it won't, then you have to put `@Lazy` to `lombok.copyableAnnotations`.

Comment: I tested but I’m not sure about the results. That’s why I’m here trying to find out the correct way of doing that

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want it only for a single class without doing a global Lombok config you can use the following snippet:

```
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Lazy))
public class AnimalService{
  @Lazy
  private DogService dogService;
}
```

Comment: According to Lombok API docs, the recommended way is `onConstructor_ ={@Lazy}` for JDK8+. For JDK7 is `onConstructor = @__(@Lazy)`. https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/AllArgsConstructor.java.

Answer (score 31):

It won't work out of the box, but you can configure Lombok to copy the `@Lazy` annotation from the field to the constructor's parameter.

**lombok.config**

```
lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy
```

The **lombok.config** should be placed in the project's root or src folder.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = {@Lazy})
public class A {
  private final B b;

  //or use this
  //@Lazy
  //private final B b;
}
```

Comment: What is the role of underscore after `onConstructor`? The property name on annotation definition is  `onConstructor` and not `onConstructor_`, I've never seen such a construction before, the documentation only denotes `note the underscore after onConstructor` without denoting for what actually it is